# using of intent for linking activities

Tags: android

I want to link my two activites by clicking on a button i have written the following code

```
public class IHBCAPTUREActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ImageView iv;
    TextView tx;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent calIntent;
        **calIntent = new Intent(IHBCAPTUREActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);**
        startActivity(calIntent);           
    }
}
```

error cumes in this line

```
calIntent = new Intent(IHBCAPTUREActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
```

for `LoginActivity.class` that

`LoginActivity cannot be resolved to a type` . How to solve it?

Comment: Maybe is a copy paste error, but what are the * at the beginning and the end?
Try to use getApplicationContext() instead IHBCAPTUREActivity.this in the Intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the simple code how you can load one activity to another,

i have created two activities like this

### FirstActivity.java

```
package com.rdc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);

        Button btnload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btnload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

---

### SecondActivity.java

```
package com.rdc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);


    }
}
```

---

and my manifest file is

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.rdc"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".FirstActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

try to implement this in your app and let me know if still any doubt is there.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have declared LoginActivity in manifest file as:

```
        <activity
            android:name="your.package-name.LoginActivity" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: i have this in my manifest

 <activity
android:name=".LoginActivity">
</activity>

Comment: does LoginActivity reside in main package or not

Comment: Depends on your package level. If you have many packages inside main package, and you have activities inside these packages, then you have to provide the fully qualified path to activity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything wrong in code.

Its know issue that occurs randomly.

solution is to set the target to other API level in project->properties->android, then set it back.then clean you project once.

I think this will refresh the .classpath or some other files, not sure, but it works.